# SCons removes space from Action/Command

Tags: scons

With the following command:

```
env.Command('XYZ', 'somefile', 'echo "Hello,    how are   you" > $TARGET')
```

SCons squashes the space and runs:

```
echo "Hello, how are you" > XYZ
```

And:

```
$ cat XYZ
Hello, how are you
```

Why is this and can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem, documented in the bugs [#1123](http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1123) and [#2018](http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2018).

In your case where you simply want to create a text file, there is a simple workaround which has the additional benefit of working cross-platform: using the Textfile Builder...

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'textfile'])

env.Textfile('XYZ','Hello,    how are   you')
```

This will create the target file with a `*.txt` extension, because that's the default of the Builder. If you don't like it, you can overwrite the variable `$TEXTFILESUFFIX`. Either globally in the Environment, or locally for a single Builder call like:

```
env.Textfile('XYZ','Hello,    how are   you', TEXTFILESUFFIX='')
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Well thank you for the info! But I cant use Textfile(), since in fact this was just an examle to show the problem, real problem is to reformat some file using sed.

Comment: You can do that in Python directly (cross-platform again) and then use the Textfile Builder. ;) Note that there is also a Substfile Builder...it replaces Variables in a text file "automake style".

Comment: I see, I see! Thanks!